# Lower bound on iterated matrix application

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices

Let $n \in \mathbb Z^2$ such that the non self-adjoint weighted Laplacian is
$$(\Delta u)(n)=u(n_1+1,n_2)-u(n_1-1,n_2) + i( u(n_1,n_2+1)- u(n_1,n_2-1))$$

the adjoint operator is then

$$(\Delta^* u)(n)=u(n_1-1,n_2)-u(n_1+1,n_2) - i( u(n_1,n_2+1)- u(n_1,n_2-1))$$

We then define the regularization operator

$$(Tu)(n):= \frac{u(n)}{\vert n \vert+1}$$

I am then interested if we can show then that there is $\lambda>0$ such that

$$\beta(n):=\Vert (T\Delta^* T \Delta)^n \delta_{0}\Vert \ge \lambda^n?$$

Here $\delta_{0}$ is the vector such that $\delta_0(0)=1$ and $\delta_0(n)=0$ for $n \neq 0.$ The norm here is the $\ell^2 $norm.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You posted a question, then you changed it to a completely different question, then you changed it back to the original question. What is going on here?

Comment: I thought one could reduce it to a combinatorical problem counting paths, but then I noticed that this assumption was wrong. Since I did not get any feedback on my original question, I thought "simplifying it" might help...

Comment: $B=T^{1/2}\Delta^*T\Delta T^{1/2}$ is self-adjoint, isn't it? Now, if $A$ is any self-adjoint operator, then $(A^2\delta_0,\delta_0)=\|A\delta_0\|^2$, so $\|A^2\delta_0\|\ge \|A\delta_0\|^2$ and the induction finishes the story.